# For each If Statement Object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I seem to be having a problem getting my `For Each` loop to ... loop ... Excel yells at me with the "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Sub killingme()
Dim i As Integer, o As Integer

i = 2
o = 2

For Each r In Worksheets("Stats").Rows
If r.Range(Cells(i, 5)).Value = 9386 And r.Range(Cells(i, 6)) = 3486 Then
r.EntireRow.Cut
Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(o).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
o = o + 1
Stop
End If
i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```

This particular sheet has roughly 58k rows that i need to loop through and move to different sheets. I have been searching for over 2 hours and haven't found a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
Sub killingme()
Dim i As Integer, o As Integer

i = 2
o = 2

For Each r In Worksheets("Stats").Rows
    If Cells(r.Row, 5).Value = 9386 And Cells(r.Row, 6) = 3486 Then
        r.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(o & ":" & o).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        r.EntireRow.Delete
        o = o + 1
        Stop
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```